# accessing Adapter data Android

Tags: android, listview, callback, spinner

I am working on an application for Android in Android Studio.

I am trying to update a ListView with new data after a selection change in my spinner.  The ListView and Spinner are in the same activity.  This is code from my onItemSelected call back for the spinner...

```
            ListView teamList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playerView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> tempAdp =  (ArrayAdapter<String>) teamList.getAdapter();

            String[] myNewStringArrayData =  myMethodToCreateNewData();

            tempAdp.clear();
            tempAdp.addAll(myNewStringArrayData);
            tempAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

My ListView Adapter is a ArrayAdapter"caret"String"caret"  type so I am trying to cast to that type.  I inspect the returned tempAdp variable in the debugger and it looks good.  I can see the old string Data in the Object list.  When I call tempAdp.clear() the app crashes with a RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From what I am seeing you are not setting an adapter to the listview

Comment: I added a list of code to test if the tempAdp is a valid object and it is.  I can tempAdp.getItem(0) and it returns the string.  I commented out the tempAdp.clear(); and tempAdp.addAll() calls and left in the notifyDataSetChanged() and the app does not crash.  I don't know why the clear crashes it.

Comment: Where is the ListView Adapter, I don't see it in the code?

Comment: You are calling getAdapter, but you are not setting an adapter to the ListView.

Comment: I set the adapter to the ListView in the OnCreate function.  The code I am showing in my post is in the onItemSelected method.  I went back to the onCreate method and tried to call the clear() method on the adapter right after I finished setting it up.  It crashed.  I must be creating the adapter incorrectly or something.

Comment: If you post your code I can help.  You should always post all of the code that has to do with your question.